Problem using Spring AOP with Java FX Controller
I have integrated Java FX with Spring boot using javafx-weaver-spring-boot-starter of net.rgielen. I want to execute some code before the call of a method of the controller, but I am getting NullPointerException when accessing @FXML annotated attributes.
I have an annotation called FooterPaieConnStatus:
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface FooterPaieConnStatus {

}

I have an Aspect on this annotation :
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j(topic = "AppLog")
public class FooterPaieConnStatusAspect {
    
    @Before("@annotation(FooterPaieConnStatus)")
    public void beforeMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        // Get connection
        boolean isConnSucessful = PaieDAOHelper.getInstance().testConn();
        // Get the target object
        Object target = joinPoint.getTarget();
        if (target instanceof MyBaseTemplatedController controller) {
            log.info("Defining footer paie connection status {} for MyBaseTemplatedController or it Subtype", isConnSucessful);
            controller.getFooterController().setIsPaieConnectionSuccesFul(isConnSucessful);
        }

    }
}

And I've used the annotation like this in my FXML Controller:
@FooterPaieConnStatus
public void synchroniserRubriques() {
        actionWithLoading("Synchronisation des rubriques en cours...", 
        ()->{
            try {
                mRubriqueService.fetchRubriques(); 
                pRubriques.getPageFactory().call(0);
                NotificationFactory.succesSync();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage());
                NotificationFactory.error("Etat de l'action", e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

Here is the beginning of the FXML Controller :
@Slf4j
@Getter
@Component
@FxmlView("/view/parametres_rubriques_comptes.fxml")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ParamListMappingController extends MyBaseTemplatedController

And inside we have the FXML Controller:
@FXML 
protected HeaderController headerController;
@FXML 
protected FooterController footerController;

But when loading the FXML Controller I have this exception (headerController is null) :
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1858)
    at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1726)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base@21/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.controls@21/javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:459)
    at javafx.controls@21/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1415)
    at javafx.controls@21/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$12(ContextMenuContent.java:1368)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@21/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@21/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3984)
    at javafx.graphics@21/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1890)
    at javafx.graphics@21/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2708)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacView.notifyMouse(MacView.java:127)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:72)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor88.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.base@21/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:270)
    at javafx.fxml@21/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1855)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: net.rgielen.fxweaver.core.FxLoadException: Unable to load FXML file file:/Users/macbook/Projets/MyReports/Realisation/myreports-desktop/target/classes/view/parametres_rubriques_comptes.fxml
    at net.rgielen.fxweaver.core.FxWeaver.loadByViewUsingFxmlLoader(FxWeaver.java:400)
    at net.rgielen.fxweaver.core.FxWeaver.loadByView(FxWeaver.java:385)
    at net.rgielen.fxweaver.core.FxWeaver.lambda$load$0(FxWeaver.java:380)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260)
    at net.rgielen.fxweaver.core.FxWeaver.load(FxWeaver.java:380)
    at net.rgielen.fxweaver.core.FxWeaver.load(FxWeaver.java:347)
    at net.rgielen.fxweaver.core.FxWeaver.load(FxWeaver.java:320)
    at com.gconcept.myreports.desktop.infra.fx.ViewManager.changeToWithFooterRefresh(ViewManager.java:104)
    at com.gconcept.myreports.desktop.infra.fx.ViewManager.changeToParamMapping(ViewManager.java:73)
    at com.gconcept.myreports.desktop.admin.controller.HeaderController.parametresMapping(HeaderController.java:66)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/Users/macbook/Projets/MyReports/Realisation/myreports-desktop/target/classes/view/parametres_rubriques_comptes.fxml

    at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2700)
    at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2547)
    at net.rgielen.fxweaver.core.FxWeaver.loadByViewUsingFxmlLoader(FxWeaver.java:397)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.gconcept.myreports.desktop.admin.controller.HeaderController.getTitle()" because "this.headerController" is null
    at com.gconcept.myreports.desktop.infra.core.MyBaseTemplatedController.setHeaderTitle(MyBaseTemplatedController.java:22)
    at com.gconcept.myreports.desktop.business.controller.ParamListMappingController.initialize(ParamListMappingController.java:110)
    at com.gconcept.myreports.desktop.business.controller.ParamListMappingController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bd8f4350.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at com.gconcept.myreports.desktop.business.controller.ParamListMappingController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c1c63611.initialize(<generated>)
    at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2670)


I'm not sure, but it might help if you post your FXML file along with the code that loads that FXML file.

Welcome to SO and thanks for the interesting question. Please learn how to ask a question on SO and provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. Ideally, post a minimal Maven project on GitHub. Thank you. I have an idea what could be wrong, but I do not feel inclined to create a full project from your fragmentary code, guessing what the missing rest might look like.

Are these nested FXML (using fx:include)? If so, make sure the controller names are specified correctly. It's really not clear to me exactly what will happen in the interplay between FXML injection and AOP proxies. The latter use (I think) bytecode manipulation to create the proxy classes, so really weird things can sometimes happen if you use them outside their intended use cases. I'd recommend creating a [mre].

As James_D explained before, you are facing Spring AOP and Spring IoC container mismatch. Apart from the excellent jewelsea answer, there is an alternate solution: using Jakarta CDI (Weld) instead of Spring/SpringBoot. This library includes Interceptors(https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#interceptors) out of the box as part of the IoC container. Frameworks like mvvmFX supports CDI integration.

I did find a way to make this work, which I added to my answer. But it is truly horrific.

Friendly reminder: Maybe, you want to decide, which one of the answers given to accept in order to mark the question as solved. Both James_D and I did our best to comprehensively show you alternatives.

Advice
In my opinion:

Keep fxml controllers super dumb.
Try to eliminate or minimize public interfaces on controllers.
Don’t use AOP or inheritance in controllers (for most cases).
Place most business logic in separate dependency-injected services.
To manage shared state, bind or subscribe to properties in injected services or model classes.

Alternate implementations
Alternates to inheritance are composition using fx:include or replacing scene nodes.
Alternates to AOP are MVC with properties and binding.
Background
AOP is a way of programming by side effect.
JavaFX properties and bindings allow you to do similar things as they also can trigger listeners or updated values as side effects.  JavaFX properties and binding are part of the JavaFX framework and all of the inbuilt objects in JavaFX are coded to integrate with JavaFX properties.  An advantage of using them in code that integrates with your GUI is that they form a natural way to integrate your code and state with the GUI.
If you prefer coding to reactive streams rather than bindings and listeners, then you could use reactfx instead.
The JavaFX event framework is a way to trigger code based on events.  You can create custom events that will trigger side effects in event filters and handlers, but usually, it is easier to use properties and binding or listeners instead.
If the code is completely separate from the GUI, then alternate mechanisms like AOP may deserve more consideration.
Example
This example demonstrates using alternate mechanisms to create a page with a footer.
The mechanisms used are:

fx:include to include one fxml in another.
composition of controllers and services via Spring dependency injection.
property binding to respond to side effects.

The functionality is somewhat similar to what you provided in your question's snippets. Still, it won't be directly applicable, and you will need to either adjust it to your requirements or implement a different solution.
The example uses a non-modular project.  To execute the example, you can download the JavaFX SDK and provide appropriate module VM parameters, substituting the SDK path with the path to your SDK.
--module-path /<SDK Path>/javafx-sdk-22.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

While you could try to use inheritance and AOP in controllers instead of the solution proposed here, it may be less likely to work well (or at all) in conjunction with SceneBuilder and the FXMLLoader.


The example uses a button to check the connection status, but you could replace the button and action call with a direct call to check the connection status when the page is loaded (or at any other specific time that you want to check the connection status).
The example does not use the third-party javafx-weaver framework, but you could use that if you wished.  Instead the example is based on the code from:

Adding Spring Dependency Injection in JavaFX (JPA Repo, Service)

Example source code
page.fxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.example.connection.PageController">
   <center>
      <StackPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: azure;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="connect" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Test connection" />
         </children>
      </StackPane>
   </center>
   <bottom>
      <fx:include fx:id="footer" source="footer.fxml" />
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>

footer.fxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<HBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.example.connection.FooterController">
    <children>
        <Pane HBox.hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RadioButton fx:id="connectionStatus" disable="true" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Connection Status" />
    </children>
</HBox>

ConnectionSpringApplication
package org.example.connection;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ConnectionSpringApplication {}

ConnectionFXApplication.java
package org.example.connection;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ConnectionFXApplication extends Application {
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;
    private Parent root;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        springContext = SpringApplication.run(ConnectionSpringApplication.class);
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("page.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
        root = fxmlLoader.load();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        springContext.stop();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(ConnectionFXApplication.class, args);
    }
}

ConnectionService.java
package org.example.connection;

import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

@Component
public class ConnectionService {
    private final ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper connected = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper(false);

    public boolean testConnection() {
        // normally we would check the connection here, but for demo purposes we just return a random connection status.
        connected.set(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean());

        return isConnected();
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        return connected.get();
    }

    public ReadOnlyBooleanProperty connectedProperty() {
        return connected.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }
}

PageController.java
package org.example.connection;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class PageController {
    // injecting the footerController is not necessary for this example.
    // the injection is just provided to show how it could be done.
    @FXML
    private FooterController footerController;

    @FXML
    private Button connect;

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionService connectionService;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        connect.setOnAction(_ -> testConnection());
    }

    private void testConnection() {
        System.out.println("Connection test result: " + connectionService.testConnection());
    }
}

FooterController.java
package org.example.connection;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class FooterController {
    @FXML
    private RadioButton connectionStatus;

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionService connectionService;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        connectionStatus.selectedProperty().bind(
                connectionService.connectedProperty()
        );
    }
}

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>connection</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>22</java.version>
        <javafx.version>22.0.2</javafx.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>


[Edited to include ugly, not-recommended, workaround]
This is mostly a description of why you see this issue: I have a workaround which I suggest at the end, but in my opinion the correct solution is "don't try to do this". Alternative approaches are given in jewelsea's excellent answer and I will not attempt to improve on those here.
Spring AOP works by creating proxies for the classes which are advised by AOP. See the documentation for more details.
The basic idea is that when you advise a method in spring-managed class with AOP, spring creates a proxy class. Conceptually, you can think of the proxy class as having the same set of methods as the "real" target class, and having a reference to an instance of that target class. If you have "before advice" configured on a method (for example), then the implementation of the method in the proxy will first invoke the advise, and then will invoke the "real" method on the target class.
To integrate Spring with JavaFX and FXML, you configure the FXMLLoader to use the Spring bean factory to create its controllers as Spring-managed beans. So when you load the FXML file, the FXMLLoader requests a controller instance from Spring. For each element in the FXML file with a fx:id attribute, it then inspects the controller, using reflection to see if there is a matching field with the same name as the attribute. If it finds one, it sets that field to the instance created by the corresponding FXML element. For event handlers, it registers an event handler on the control which invokes the specified method on the controller.
So what happens when your FXML controller is managed by Spring and is advised by Spring AOP? The Spring container creates two objects: the "real" target object which is an actual instance of your controller class, and a proxy object which conceptually has a reference to that target. The object it returns to the requestor of the spring bean is the proxy object. The FXMLLoader will set the field in the controller it is aware of - the proxy, not the target. Since the FXMLLoader doesn't have a direct reference to the target object, it cannot set the field in the target.
When the event handler is invoked, it is invoked on the proxy, which first invokes your before advice, and then invokes the handler method on the target. Since the FXMLLoader never saw the actual target instance, it could not inject the @FXML-annotated fields there, and they are null.
There's basically a mismatch here between the way Spring AOP works (proxying methods) and the way the FXMLLoader works (injecting fields into instances). I really don't see a way this can be worked around because of this mismatch. It's not particularly clear this is a good use of AOP anyway. The general use case for AOP is for cross cutting concerns that you want to apply at disparate parts of the application (transactions, logging, performance profiling, etc.) If your advice implementation is checking the class of the target and invoking methods on it, then you're fairly clearly not using this for cross cutting concerns. So there may be some way to force this to work, using perhaps AOPContext.currentProxy() or something similar, but my recommendation (for what it's worth) would be to refactor the design of this part of the application.
Ugly workaround
The above-referenced documentation does suggest a workaround, but that documentation strongly recommends not doing this, and I re-iterate that advice here. But in case you really want to proceed with this approach you can do the following.
As described above, the FXMLLoader will inject fields into instances of the proxy, not into the instances of the target on which the event handler methods are ultimately invoked. So if you're controller class can get a reference to the proxy, it can retrieve the @FXML-injected field from the proxy.
To make this work, you need to instruct Spring AOP to expose the proxy objects. In your @SpringBootApplication class you probably have a @EnableAspectJAutoProxy annotation. You can add the following attribute to expose the proxies:
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(exposeProxy = true)

If you are configuring the application differently, there are various equivalent ways to provide this parameter.
Now, in your controller, to access the @FXML-injected fields you can do something like the following:
public void setHeaderTitle(String title) {

    // String currentTitle = headerController.getTitle();
    String currentTitle = ((HeaderController)AopContext.currentProxy()).headerController.getTitle();
    // ...
}

Note that you have to do this for access to any @FXML-injected field. Also note that this will only work if the class has a proxy, that is, if there is a method in the class with advice applied to it.
The documentation already points out one objection to this: that your client code now has a dependency on the Spring API, which is not desirable. But the last point I raised creates a far worse problem: your controller code has to "know" if it is being advised or not. This completely negates all the benefits of using AOP in the first place.
So again, I do not recommend this approach, and I agree with others that using AOP in FXML controllers is not advisable (pun intended). This will lead to trouble further down your maintenance road. But the workaround/hack is there if you need it.
Complete Example for Testing
Here is a complete example for those interested in testing.
Implementation notes:
There's a lot of discussion on this site on the "best" way to start up a Spring Boot and JavaFX application. The general consensus is that you should either bypass the standard Spring Boot startup and let the default startup for a JavaFX application manually start the Spring container, or vice versa and bypass the standard JavaFX application startup and manually start the JavaFX runtime. I chose the latter. This also does not use any Spring/JavaFX integration framework such as Javafx-weaver but just uses a SpringFXMLLoader bean that knows how to load an FXML file specifying the Spring IOC container as the controller factory. I just dumped everything (except module-info.java) in a single package called org.jamesd.examples.springfx.
SpringApp.java:
package org.jamesd.example.springfx;

import javafx.application.Platform;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(exposeProxy = true)
public class SpringApp implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private UiApp app ;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringApp.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        Platform.startup(app::start);
    }
}

LoggedMethod.java
package org.jamesd.example.springfx;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface LoggedMethod {
}

LoggingAspect.java
package org.jamesd.example.springfx;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {
    @Before("@annotation(LoggedMethod)")
    public void logMethodEntry(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        Object target = joinPoint.getTarget();
        System.out.println("Entering method "+joinPoint.getSignature()+" in "+target+" ("+target.getClass()+")");
    }
}

MessageProvider.java
package org.jamesd.example.springfx;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MessageProvider {
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Welcome to JavaFX with Spring";
    }
}

UiApp.java
package org.jamesd.example.springfx;

import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class UiApp {

    @Autowired
    private SpringFXMLLoader loader;

    public void start() {
        try {
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            Parent root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 320, 240);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

SpringFXMLLoader.java
package org.jamesd.example.springfx;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.net.URL;

@Component
public class SpringFXMLLoader {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public Parent load(URL resource) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(resource);
        loader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);
        return loader.load();
    }
}

hello-view.fxml (Using Maven and the standard layout, this is in src/main/resources/org/jamesd/examples/springfx, i.e. in the same package as the Java code but under resources to ensure it is deployed to the classpath.)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="org.jamesd.example.springfx.HelloController">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
    </padding>

    <Label fx:id="welcomeText"/>
    <Button text="Hello!" onAction="#onHelloButtonClick"/>
</VBox>

HelloController.java
package org.jamesd.example.springfx;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import org.springframework.aop.framework.AopContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private MessageProvider messageProvider;
    @FXML
    private Label welcomeText;

    @FXML
    @LoggedMethod
    public void onHelloButtonClick() {
        // works if no proxy:
//        welcomeText.setText(messageProvider.getMessage());
        // horrible hack to make this work if there's a proxy:
        ((HelloController) AopContext.currentProxy()).welcomeText.setText(messageProvider.getMessage());
    }
}

module-info.java
module org.jamesd.example.springfx {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.boot.starter;
    requires spring.context;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.aop;
    requires org.aspectj.weaver;

    opens org.jamesd.example.springfx to javafx.fxml;
    exports org.jamesd.example.springfx;
}

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.jamesd.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springfx</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.8.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>21.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>21.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.19</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


In the spirit of jewelsea's answer a better approach here is to make the controller as dumb as possible, eliminating any public interface, removing any AOP in the controller, delegating to an injected service, and moving the business logic and AOP to the service.
For example, if we introduce a WelcomeService:
package org.jamesd.example.springfx;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class WelcomeService {

    @Autowired
    private MessageProvider messageProvider;

    private final StringProperty welcomeMessage = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public StringProperty welcomeMessageProperty() {
        return welcomeMessage;
    }

    @LoggedMethod
    public void loadWelcome() {
        welcomeMessageProperty().set(messageProvider.getMessage());
    }
}

then we can refactor the controller to be as minimal as possible:
package org.jamesd.example.springfx;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private WelcomeService welcomeService;
    @FXML
    private Label welcomeText;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        welcomeText.textProperty().bind(welcomeService.welcomeMessageProperty());
    }
    @FXML
    private void onHelloButtonClick() {
        welcomeService.loadWelcome();
    }
}

(Note all the AOP is removed, and there is no public interface at all to this class.)
This approach seems far better than trying to shoehorn AOP onto a controller which arguably violates the principle of single responsibility.

You are right, that workaround defeats the whole purpose of AOP and is not recommended. I am not a Java FX guy (but sort of an AOP expert). If you happen to have an MCVE on GitHub, I could take a look and maybe suggest something else.

@kriegaex Added example directly to the answer. Note I do regard "making this work" as an entirely academic exercise. I don't really think one should make this work, and agree with jewelsea that the nature of FXML controllers makes them unsuitable candidates for AOP (or indeed inheritance, etc.). Anything that needs that should be delegated to the business layer (and Spring makes that delegation easy). It might be still interesting to see if there's a sensible way for it to work.

I do not buy this generic "unsuited for AOP" argument. Interestingly, most of the time I hear this, it comes from people not proficient in AOP. You might be an advanced AOP user, but still that statement sounds too unfoundedly opinionated to me.

@kriegaex Ideally, an FXML controller should have no non-private methods. It is intrinsically linked to a specific FXML file and no methods should be invoked on it from any Java code (they are only invoked by reflection by the FXMLLoader). It’s hard to see any use case for AOP (at least, within the restrictions of Sprong AOP) in a class where all the methods are private.

@kriegaex Of course, reasonable people can (and do, and should) disagree on such things, and I think your knowledge of AOP far outweighs mine. If I am “unreasonably opinionated”, though, it’s more likely to be through my opinions on FXML controllers, where I claim some degree of expertise.

I said "unfoundedly opinionated", not "unreasonably". Most of what you say is reasonable and knowledgeable, very much so. You did not give any compelling reasons for not using AOP other than saying that the nature of FXML controllers makes them unsuited for AOP, which IMO makes the AOP criticism somewhat unfounded.

I agree with the other people who answered here insofar as AOP does not replace good application design and separation of concerns. Actually, the whole point of AOP is to support separation of concerns and extend that to cross-cutting ones, too.
Having said that, if we take the original code from James_D's answer before refactoring and modify it to use
  @FXML
  @LoggedMethod
  public void onHelloButtonClick() {
    welcomeText.setText(messageProvider.getMessage());
  }

without exposing any AOP proxies and then simply switch to native AspectJ (which functions without proxies), it just works. Simply select the right AOP tool for the job.
Modify the aspect pointcut to limit matching to execution joinpoints (Spring AOP does that implicitly, being less powerful than AspectJ) and to no longer be a Spring @Component:
package org.jamesd.example.springfx;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {
  @Before("@annotation(LoggedMethod) && execution(* *(..))")
  public void logMethodEntry(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    Object target = joinPoint.getTarget();
    System.out.println("Entering method " + joinPoint.getSignature() + " in " + target + " (" + target.getClass() + ")");
  }
}

Bump the AspectJ version to 1.9.22.1 to avoid a fixed bug from 1.9.19:
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.22.1</version>
    </dependency>

Add resource file src/main/resources/org/aspectj/aop.xml as follows:
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "https://eclipse.dev/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
  <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
    <include within="org.jamesd..*"/>
  </weaver>
  <aspects>
    <aspect name="org.jamesd.example.springfx.LoggingAspect"/>
  </aspects>
</aspectj>

Now start the application with JVM parameter -javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver-1.9.22.1.jar. Et voilà! It works without shoehorning anything into anything.
Console log when not using modular Java (I never do), starting the Spring Boot application and clicking the button a few times:
[AppClassLoader@76ed5528] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.9.22.1 built on Friday May 10, 2024 at 23:23:16 PDT
[AppClassLoader@76ed5528] info register classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@76ed5528
[AppClassLoader@76ed5528] info using configuration /C:/Users/me/Documents/java-src/SO_AJ_SpringJavaFX_78775257/target/classes/org/aspectj/aop.xml
[AppClassLoader@76ed5528] info register aspect org.jamesd.example.springfx.LoggingAspect

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.6)

2024-07-25T08:31:13.942+02:00  INFO 10880 --- [           main] org.jamesd.example.springfx.SpringApp    : Starting SpringApp using Java 21 with PID 10880 (C:\Users\me\Documents\java-src\SO_AJ_SpringJavaFX_78775257\target\classes started by me in C:\Users\me\Documents\java-src\SO_AJ_SpringJavaFX_78775257)
2024-07-25T08:31:13.947+02:00  INFO 10880 --- [           main] org.jamesd.example.springfx.SpringApp    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[AppClassLoader@76ed5528] weaveinfo at org\jamesd\example\springfx\HelloController.java:23::0 Join point 'method-execution(void org.jamesd.example.springfx.HelloController.onHelloButtonClick())' in Type 'org.jamesd.example.springfx.HelloController' (HelloController.java:23) advised by before advice from 'org.jamesd.example.springfx.LoggingAspect' (LoggingAspect.java)
    see also: org\jamesd\example\springfx\LoggingAspect.java::0
2024-07-25T08:31:14.786+02:00  INFO 10880 --- [           main] org.jamesd.example.springfx.SpringApp    : Started SpringApp in 1.434 seconds (process running for 2.797)
2024-07-25T08:31:14.799+02:00  WARN 10880 --- [           main] javafx                                   : Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @379614be'
[MethodUtil@f5d9a15] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.9.22.1 built on Friday May 10, 2024 at 23:23:16 PDT
[MethodUtil@f5d9a15] info register classloader sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil@f5d9a15
[MethodUtil@f5d9a15] info using configuration /C:/Users/me/Documents/java-src/SO_AJ_SpringJavaFX_78775257/target/classes/org/aspectj/aop.xml
[MethodUtil@f5d9a15] info register aspect org.jamesd.example.springfx.LoggingAspect
[MethodUtil@6c8337fd] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.9.22.1 built on Friday May 10, 2024 at 23:23:16 PDT
[MethodUtil@6c8337fd] info register classloader com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil@6c8337fd
[MethodUtil@6c8337fd] info using configuration /C:/Users/me/Documents/java-src/SO_AJ_SpringJavaFX_78775257/target/classes/org/aspectj/aop.xml
[MethodUtil@6c8337fd] info register aspect org.jamesd.example.springfx.LoggingAspect
Entering method void org.jamesd.example.springfx.HelloController.onHelloButtonClick() in org.jamesd.example.springfx.HelloController@303a61a1 (class org.jamesd.example.springfx.HelloController)
Entering method void org.jamesd.example.springfx.HelloController.onHelloButtonClick() in org.jamesd.example.springfx.HelloController@303a61a1 (class org.jamesd.example.springfx.HelloController)
Entering method void org.jamesd.example.springfx.HelloController.onHelloButtonClick() in org.jamesd.example.springfx.HelloController@303a61a1 (class org.jamesd.example.springfx.HelloController)
Entering method void org.jamesd.example.springfx.HelloController.onHelloButtonClick() in org.jamesd.example.springfx.HelloController@303a61a1 (class org.jamesd.example.springfx.HelloController)


That's cool. I haven't tested, but I'm guess this would still work if you make the onHelloButtonClick() method private, which somewhat better preserves encapsulation. Guess I need to add native ApsectJ on the list of things to learn and understand...

While with so-called privileged aspects it is possible to advise private methods, I do not recommend to do so, because it breaks encapsulation semantically (and technically). If an aspect needs to add functionality to private methods, probably something is wrong with your API and module structure.

That returns to my overall reluctance to do this. From an encapsulation perspective, FXML controller methods really should be private. (This may be something of an "unfounded opinion", though I think I can defend this position. FXML controllers are not MVC controllers in the web-app sense.) Given that, advising a controller with AOP generally seems like the wrong approach. But YMMV, of course.

You guys get happy with your own Java FX philosophy. If you want to use AOP, I showed you how to. If you don't, just let it be. Good luck, everyone.

But we agree on the AOP, no? Everyone agrees it shouldn't be used on private methods.

That does not mean that those controller methods have to be private. It also does not mean that this is not an exception to the rule for AOP usage on private methods. I don't know anything about Java FX, so I am not going to try arguing there. I am sure, though, that there is a good solution to this problem which utilises AOP without being a design nightmare. There always is, it just needs to be found. By all means, be principled - but not too dogmatic.
